# Pundit::NotDefinedError: unable to find policy `UserPolicy`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

I must be doing something wrong or I need glasses. I am following this tutorial here:

http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/09/29/using-pundit-the-cool-kid-of-authorization/

I've created the `application_policy.rb` file and `user_policy.rb` files inside the `app/policies` folder as instructed.

Pundit doesn't seem to detect my UserPolicy file inside `IntegrationTests`.

### My Setup

- Ruby on Rails 5 RC1
- Ruby 2.2.4p230
- Knock gem for JWT authentication
- Pundit 1.1.0

### user_policy.rb

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy    
  def update?
    user == resource
  end
end
```

In my UserController, I have the defined REST API actions. Currently, I'm just testing the "update" action:

### UsersController

```
def update
  user = User.find_by({id: params[:id]})

  authorize user

  render json: { error: "Failed to find" }, status: :not_found and return unless user

  if user.update!(user_params)
    render json: user
  else
    render json: { error: "Not found" }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

### users_controller_test.rb

```
test "update other user's data should raise NotAuthorized exception" do
  @user_two = users(:two)

  put user_path(@user_two.id), params: { first_name: "Jim" }, headers: @authorization_header
  assert_response :success # forcing fail test for now to test plumbing
end
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
.E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_update_other_user's_data_should_raise_NotAuthorized_exception:
Pundit::NotDefinedError: unable to find policy `UserPolicy` for `#<User id: 298486374, first_name: "MyString", last_name: "MyString", email: "MyString", password_digest: "MyString", created_at: "2016-05-27 13:30:07", updated_at: "2016-05-27 13:30:07", role_id: nil>`
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `update'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:60:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

### Edit

If it's any help, my UserControllerTest file looks like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def authenticate
    token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: users(:one).id }).token
    @authorization_header = { HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: "Bearer #{token}" }
  end

  setup do
    # load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
    Rails.application.load_seed
    authenticate
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test "logged in user should return ok" do
    get users_path, headers: @authorization_header
    assert_response :ok
  end

  test "not logged in user should return unauthorized" do
    get users_path
    assert_response :unauthorized
  end

  test "user json should not contain password_digest" do
    get user_path(@user.id), headers: @authorization_header
    assert_response :ok
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    assert json.key?("password_digest") == false
  end

  test "create user without authorization header should return created" do
    user = {
      first_name: "Bob",
      last_name: "Brown",
      email: "bob@gmail.com",
      password: "abc",
      password_confirmation: "abc"
    }

    post users_path, params: user
    assert_response :created
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    assert !json.empty?
  end

  test "update user should return ok" do
    put user_path(@user.id), params: { first_name: "Bob"}, headers: @authorization_header
    assert_response :ok

    updated_user = User.find_by({id: @user.id})

    assert_equal "Bob", updated_user.first_name
  end

  test "update other user's data should raise NotAuthorized exception" do
    @user_two = users(:two)

    put user_path(@user_two.id), params: { first_name: "Jim" }, headers: @authorization_header
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "delete user shoudl return ok" do
    assert_difference "User.count", -1 do
      delete user_path(@user.id), headers: @authorization_header
    end
  end
end
```

All my tests were passing before I added the Pundit stuff an hour ago.

Comment: Is the file actually called `UserPolicy.rb`? It is a strong convention in ruby to name files in lower case, with underscores, like: `user_policy.rb`. If this is the case, then that's your problem.

Comment: Sorry, bad typing mistakes. No, the file is called `user_policy.rb`

Comment: So to clarify, is it *only* the test that's not working? If you run the server and perform an action manually, does it work?

Comment: I tested using Postman by making PUT request to update another user and my Rails server returned `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError (not allowed to update? ...` which is telling me it's working inside the controller. So it appears like it's just the IntegrationTest that's the problem. Could it be a file referencing problem ? If it is, why does my controller recognize it but my integration test file not recognize it?

Comment: Can your test suite autoload other constants like your models? Could it be that you could have forgot to require `test_helper.rb` in your test?

Comment: Could also be that the rails server needs to be restarted to pick up on and start autoloading for new folders in `/app`. If you are using a forker like spring you might want to restart it.

Comment: Just to add to this, are you using `spring` to run tests? This *should* restart itself automatically when, for example, you update gem dependencies -- but doing a forced manual restart is worth a shot.

Comment: My tests are able to load my User models, I don't know if I am using Spring to run test, when I run `rails test` it does say `Running via Spring preloader`. I use the default Rails 5 API mode setup, I believe it's Mini Test ? I believe tests work without the need for the server to be running, all the past test has worked and indicated so...

Comment: Someone told me in Gitter Rails chat `bundle exec rails test` ignores Spring, maybe that might have been the safer option to test the issue for anyone in the future reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay....I don't know what the heck happened but apparently, I quit all my Mac terminal AND Atom IDE where I typed my code.

Then I opened my terminal and did a `rails test` command again, and this time it worked:

```
....E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_update_other_user's_data_should_raise_NotAuthorized_exception:
Pundit::NotAuthorizedError: not allowed to update? this #<User id: 298486374, first_name: "MyString", last_name: "MyString", email: "MyString", password_digest: "MyString", created_at: "2016-05-27 15:19:51", updated_at: "2016-05-27 15:19:51", role_id: nil>
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `update'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:60:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Bizarre...

### TL;DR

1. Quit your IDE and Terminal
2. Reopen your Terminal, then try again

Answer (score 3):

To fix, I ran:

```
bin/spring stop
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
bundle update spring
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```